# Get data from mplot3d graph

Tags: matplotlib, mplot3d

I can’t find out how to get data from an mplot3d graph. Something similar to the 2D style:

```
line.get_xdata()
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Line3D

You can get get the original data from the (private) `_verts3d` attribute

```
xdata, ydata, zdata = line._verts3d
print(xdata)
```

Complete example

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Prepare arrays x, y, z
x = np.arange(5)
y = np.arange(5)*4
z = np.arange(5)*100

line, = ax.plot(x, y, z, label='curve')

fig.canvas.draw()

xdata, ydata, zdata = line._verts3d
print(xdata)  # This prints [0 1 2 3 4]

plt.show()
```

---

Some explanation: The problem with `get_data` or `get_xdata` is that it will return the projected coordinates once the figure is drawn. So while before drawing the figure, `line.get_xdata()` would indeed return the correct values, after drawing, it would return something like

```
[ -6.14413090e-02  -3.08824862e-02  -3.33066907e-17   3.12113190e-02 6.27567511e-02]
```

in the above example, which is the x component of the 3D coordinates projected onto 2D.

---

There is a [pull request to matplotlib](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/10111), which would allow to get the data via methods `get_data_3d`. This is still not merged, but might allow the above to be done without using private arguments in a future version of matplotlib.

## Poly3DCollection

For a `plot_surface` plot this looks similar, except that the attribute to look at is the `._vec`

```
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
xdata, ydata, zdata, _ = surf._vec
print(xdata)
```

Comment: Excellent answer, and I will accept. But I was not specific enough. I have problems with a plot_surface graph. Is there a similar way for surface graphs?

Comment: Short follow up: The data has lost its dimensions. It’s now a one dimensional nearest. I want to use the data to make a replot. How do I retrieve the original dimensions?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can easily do that actually.

Comment: FYI: the PR has been merged and the feature will be in the next release it seems so.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was filed on Github and there is contribution that adds new `get_data_3d` and `set_data_3d` methods. Unfortunately, these changes is likely not yet available in distributions. So you might have to continue using private variable `line._verts3d`.

See more here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8914